# Setup the VSCode debugger for python 2.7 and Django 1.11

Tags: django, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

I already setup a debugger for an existing django 1,11 project on vscode with the Microsoft python extension, but this will only works on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (the homepage) I need this debugger to be hooked to my already running server on http://localhost:8000/
I need a setup that allows me to debug on vscode, make the code stop at specific breakpoints, debug code for various URLs using google chrome.
This is my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Python 2.7
Django 1.11
Visual Studio Code
MacOS Catalina
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Use 8000 as shown below in your setup**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "8000",                    
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```